# Title (<title>) of wordpress site is not proper

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress title of the page is divided by `|`. In my project On my front page title is fine (e.g. title | title). But in the inner pages title is not complete. Its not showing second part after | (symbol).

I have tried

```
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php is_front_page() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

But it does not show anything after | symbol (in inner pages).

I have also tried `wp_title()`. But its start showing url in the title instead of name/title. What else I can try to make my title correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fond a solution with the help of [THIS POST](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/site-url-in-tab-instead-of-site-title)

Just did little bit changes in the solution of that post and its working fine now.

```
<title><?php if (is_front_page()) { bloginfo('name');echo ' | ';bloginfo('description'); } elseif ( is_category() ) { single_cat_title(); echo ' - ' ; bloginfo('name'); }
elseif (is_single() ) { single_post_title(); }
elseif (is_page() ) { bloginfo('name'); echo ' | '; single_post_title(); }
else { wp_title('',true); } ?></title>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code

1. Prints the name of your website
2. Prints a pipe (|)
3. a. If it's the home page, it prints the description of your website (“Tagline” set in Settings > General)
4. b. If not, it prints the title of the current page

If it's printing `{blog_title} | {blank}` it most likely means something is wrong with the Page title. In the WP Admin, ensure the Page you're viewing has a Title set.

Alternatively, an SEO plugin is conflicting with the title function - try disabling plugins one by one and see if it impacts the output.

References: 
[Bloginfo](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/), [is_front_page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page),  [wp_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/)

Comment: There is not plugin conflicting issue and my all pages has title. But its still not working. Can you suggest any alternate code for it that can work. Or by any chance any function of functions.php can be the cause of that?

Comment: Can you look through your functions file for something that modifies the title? Specifically the code I'm thinking of uses the [wp_title filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_title/) which would look like `apply_filters ( 'wp_title', 'some_function');` Then look at `some_function` and perhaps it's messing up somehow.

Answer (score 2):

From [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Title_Tag):

```
<?php
    if ( ! function_exists( '_wp_render_title_tag' ) ) :
        function theme_slug_render_title() {
        ?>
            <title><?php wp_title( ' ', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
            <?php
        }
        add_action( 'wp_head', 'theme_slug_render_title' );
    endif;
?>
```

> Since Version 4.1, themes should use add_theme_support() in the functions.php file in order to support title tag, like so:

Comment: Its showing url instead of title. However i have found solution. Thx for help

Comment: You must have some filter that changes the `wp_title()` then. It should post your site name and blog title...

Comment: Yes, I know! In my previous projects it was working fine BUT in the current project because of some reasons this function is not working. But its working fine with the solution I have got from wordpress support post, I have posted it as answer with little modification in the code as per need of my project.

Comment: Well I'm glad that it's working, but be sure to find out what's causing this, as it could cause some headache later on ;)